# Divisibility by 7 involving grouping and alternating sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove Number in decimal representation $N=abc,def,ghi,\cdots ,xyz$ is divisible by $7$.
Iff $abc-def+ghi-\cdots+xyz$, alternating sum of numbers formed by dividing the string $N$ into $3$ digit pairs of consecutive digits. Is divisible by $7$.

Comment: Works for 13 too.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N=\sum_{i=0}^{3n-1} a_i\cdot 10^{i}$. Since $10^3+1$ is divisible by $7$, modulo $7$ for each $k$ we have $$a_{3k+2}\cdot 10^{3k+2}+a_{3k+1}\cdot 10^{3k+1}+a_{3k}\cdot 10^{3k}\equiv$$
$$(a_{3k+2}\cdot 100+a_{3k+1}\cdot 10+a_{3k})\cdot 10^{3k}\equiv$$

$$(a_{3k+2}\cdot 100+a_{3k+1}\cdot 10+a_{3k})\cdot (-1)^{k},$$

which implies the required claim.

Comment: $(-1)^k$ at the end, I guess

Comment: @PeterFranek Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $7$ divides $10^{3(2n+1)}+1$ and $10^{3(2n)}-1$, this is easy to see by Fermat
\begin{eqnarray*}
10^{6n} \equiv 1 \pmod{7} \\
10^{6n+3} \equiv -1 \pmod{7}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So $7 \mid 10^{3n} a_n b_n c_n + 10^{3(n-1)} a_{n-1} b_{n-1} c_{n-1} +\cdots +10^{3} a_1 b_1 c_1 + a_0 b_0 c_0 $ if and only if $7 \mid (-1)^{n} a_n b_n c_n + (-1)^{n-1} a_{n-1} b_{n-1} c_{n-1} +\cdots - a_1 b_1 c_1 + a_0 b_0 c_0 $.